# Django - Creating an instance via the serializer with a foreign key reference

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have a agencies and users. I want to create `User` instances via the `UserSerializer` which have an `agency_id`. However the serializer's `validated_data` does not have the `agency_id` after calling `is_valid()`.

```
class Agency(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class User(modes.Model):
    username =  models.CharField(max_length=60)
    agency   =  models.ForeignKey(Agency, blank=True, null=True)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        User = get_user_model()
        model = User

        fields = ( 'id', 'username', 'agency_id' )

        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

Try to create a user via the serializer which belongs to the Acme Agency:

```
agency = Agency.objects.create(name="Acme Agency")
serializer = UserSerializer(data={ 'username':'wiley', 'agency_id': agency.id} )

serializer.is_valid() # True
serializer.validated_data.get('agency_id') # None
```

Creating a user via the UserManager using the agency id works just fine:

```
user = User.objects.create(username='wiley', agency_id=1)
user.agency.id # 1
```

Comment: print serializer.data after serializer.is_valid() # True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **`agency`** instead of **`agency_id`** in **UserSerializer** as

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        User = get_user_model()
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'agency')
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

and use the serailizer as,

```
serializer = UserSerializer(data={ 'username':'wiley', 'agency': agency.id} )
```

Comment: That works great! I expected the field names to mimic those of  underlying object...